# Stripping result from Python batch command

Tags: python, batch-file, split, output

I'm trying to strip the "Yes" from a windows command output in Python. But sofar im getting nowhere.
The following code:

```
result = os.open('net user ' + user + ' | find /i "Account active"').read()
```

Outputs:

```
"Account active                          Yes"
```

I want to be able to retrieve the "Yes". I used split() & strip() but that does not seem to work at all.

After working it out the correct code in my case was:

```
result = result.join(result.replace('Account active', '').split())
```

Comment: if the output is always of the form `Account active   Yes` or `Account active   No`, then you may use `result.split(" ")[-1]`

Comment: In what way does `split` and `strip` not work? What outputs are you getting? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `'Yes' in result` if you don't expect `'Yes'` anywhere else, or `result.endswith(' Yes')` if you want to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
>>> ' '.join("Account active                        Yes".replace('Yes','').split())
'Account active'
```

First replace `'Yes'` with empty space, then split to remove white spaces and the join the resulting list on single space.

---

If by "strip" `'Yes'`  you meant extract `'Yes'` then you can do it like so:

```
>>> "Account active                        Yes".split()[-1]
'Yes'
```

Comment: Thx, that helped, I was able to shorten it even to:  `result = result.join("Account active Yes".replace('Account active', '').split())`

Comment: @Ken You wanted `'Yes'` from the string or `"Account active"`? I thought you wanted `Account active`.

Comment: @Ken Updated the solution for extracting `'Yes'`

Comment: Needed "Yes" from the output, sorry for confusing you, but your solution helped me. Thanks! :)